# reCaptcha accepts wrong answers sometimes

Tags: asp.net, validation, captcha, recaptcha

We are using recaptcha ASP.NET control:

http://recaptcha.net/plugins/aspnet/

However, we find that in some situations, recaptcha accepts answers which are clearly wrong.

For example, recaptcha provided these words:

> of purser

The tester typed in the following:

> o purser

..but Page.IsValid returned true! Is this a known issue with recaptcha?

Comment: The URL you provided http://recaptcha.net/plugins/aspnet/ seems dead.

Comment: I replaced the broken link with one from archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20100414011057/http://wiki.recaptcha.net/index.php/FAQ#reCAPTCHA_is_accepting_incorrect_words

Answer (score 1):

Recaptcha is not only a validation mechanism but also help organization to digitalize scanned books to text.

Recaptcha provides *two words*, one of those word Recaptcha knows and the other one actually putting it to its database against that image *(basically you are helping recaptcha to convert image to text)*. But you don't know which one actually Recaptcha has provided you for verification.

In your case, Recaptcha given you `purser` as the verfication and `of` was considered as an answer, and your input was taken into consideration to convert **image to text**.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the two words provided by Recpatcha, it only knows one word,(and for a human it is fairly easy to guess which one), the other word is not known by the system, so it expects if the user types the known word correctly it assumes that he might also have type the other word correctly.

Read [how recaptcha works](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore) for more